# Java 8 build 45 expired certificate

Tags: windows-8, java, certificate

The Java cert on my old hardware (Dell DS2161-2) IS EXPIRED (last month) and Java is trolling me with "security". I've tried adding it and variations there of to the exception list, but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
https://172.22.15.10/connections.asp?&userId=(actualid)
http://172.22.15.10/connections.asp?&userId=(actualid)
https://172.22.15.10/connections.asp
https://172.22.15.10/*
https://172.22.15.10
https://172.22.15.*
```

What can I do?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Why can't you update the certificate?

Comment: Wildcards don't work. See [Exception Site List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/exception_site_list.html) for what is valid.  `https://172.22.15.10/connections.asp` should work. Remove the rest. Did you restart your browser?

Comment: I restarted browser, vm, device, etc...  I tried IE and Firefox both

Comment: How could I go about updating the certificate?  Connect via console and then...?

Comment: I tried removing others, that didn't work either